# Recursively search a table in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a BOM that I can get a structured look like this, where it pulls for all my products.

[image]

I'm trying to pull all members of a particular BOM recursively through VBA. so far I can get the top level items, but I cannot get anything beyond that. Can someone point me in the right direction with my code on what I need to do next? IF something better than recursion could work here I could do that as well, it was just my initial thought.

```
'getMembers gets all items of the member field
    Function getMembers(member As String) As Variant
        'declare range of BOM
        Dim rng As range
        Set rng = Worksheets("Allboms").range("All_Boms[name]")
        
        Dim i As Integer
        i = 0
        Dim members() As String
        ReDim members(1)
        
        For Each cell In rng
            If cell.Value = member Then
                members(i) = cell.Offset(, 4).Value
                i = i + 1
                ReDim Preserve members(i)
            End If
        Next
        getMembers = members
    End Function

Sub getMemberItems()
    'declare where product is
    Dim product As String
    product = range("C3").Value
    Dim item As Variant
   
    For Each item In getMembers(product)
        Debug.print item
    Next item
        
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-recursive approach using a Collection as a queue:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim m
    For Each m In getMembers("A")
        Debug.Print m
    Next m
End Sub


'getMembers gets all items of the member field
Function getMembers(member As String) As Collection
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim rv As New Collection, q As New Collection, m, v
    
    Set rng = Worksheets("Allboms").Range("All_Boms[name]")
    q.Add member 'start the queue
    
    Do While q.Count > 0
        m = q(1)
        q.Remove 1
        For Each c In rng.Cells
            If c.Value = m Then
                v = c.Offset(, 4).Value
                If Not IsError(Application.Match(v, rng, 0)) Then
                    q.Add v  'has sub-members: add to queue
                Else
                    rv.Add v 'no sub-members: add to output
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Loop
    Set getMembers = rv
End Function
```

Comment: adding a reference to mscorlib allow you to use an actual Queue, or CreateObject("System.Collections.Queue").  There is no intellisense with this object, even if early bound so you need to read here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.queue?view=net-6.0

Comment: @freeflow -  granted: this works on Mac though (their life in VBA is hard enough already ).

Comment: This worked terrifically, thanks Tim. Followup question, when you declared the collections, what does the syntax "m, v" do at the end? Does this declare fields inside of it? I realized I need to get a column value next to the member item, so I was going to do a collection inside of a collection of the column and the one next to it.

Comment: m and v are just two other variables which happen to be declared on the same line as the collections. I would post a new question if you’re having problems modifying the code- I’m away from my computer for a couple days but I’m sure someone else will help

Comment: Hey @TimWilliams I noticed an issue today when comparing what it was in the system versus what my code outputs. It looks like it isn't putting the top level members, For example, member B and C aren't shown on the output, but the parts of B and C are. I think anything tied directly to A is not outputting, because they are being removed  in 'q.remove 1'. Note to anyone using this, add 'rv.add m' before 'q.remove 1' to get top level members. Thanks Tim!

Comment: Yes it was only intended to return the "child" elements (as you already know the parent)